# looking for expression for nth-child style

Tags: css

I want to set styles for child elements in groups of 4. What expression do I need to use in `nth-child` style? The below changes styles for every fourth element. I want to have first four black/white, second four white/black, etc.

```
ul li:nth-child(4n) {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
ul li:nth-child(4n+1) {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible there's a better way, but this would work:

```
ul li:nth-child(8n+1),
ul li:nth-child(8n+2),
ul li:nth-child(8n+3),
ul li:nth-child(8n+4){
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UXgJD/